# Using `const` to declare an ES6 function doesn't make it globally available but `var` does

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make a function available everywhere once that script is loaded:

```
"use strict";
const myFunction = () => {}
```

But when I try to call `myFunction()` from another script it tells me that it doesn't exist, even though the script was loaded. If I change `const` to `var`, it works.

Funnily enough, I've written code like this for a long time and it just appeared now, yet I'm architecturing the same way.

Why is that?

Comment: Did you recently change your build process? I had this problem when I stopped transpiling ES6 code to ES5 with Babel – previously, all of my `const` and `let` declarations became `var` in the end. Very annoying to debug.

Comment: @djfdev Absolutely not. I'm not using anything besides Babel for the final transpile. No build, no nada. I just load my scripts and I have a script where I do exactly this and it works and now another script and...it doesn't work.

Comment: ***Look at the transpiled code.***  Likely Babel is wrapping this file in it's own "module" function to keep everything private except what should be explicitly global.  If this is a node.js module file, that is already wrapped in a module function to keep internal stuff private.  If this is just a browser script, then look at the transpiled Babel code to see.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm working with the un-transpiled code as of now. I don't use modules or anything. Just files.

Comment: It's difficult to say anything conclusive without seeing the other code that works

Comment: Well, you said in a previous comment ***I'm not using anything besides Babel for the final transpile.***  That sure sounds like you're transpiling.

Comment: @DanPantry No joke, it's literally exactly what I provided in my question and it works. I'm working with files / const only.

Comment: If you're solely concerned with why something changed from before, then there is NO way to know without seeing the transpiled code both before and after.  It's possible that Babel fixed/changed some issues that led to this change or your configuration for Babel changed somehow.  That's certainly not anything we can know without seeing both before and after in the transpiled code.

Comment: @jfriend00 I understand and you're right. I have no idea how I could even ask this question for it to make sense.

Comment: It also seems you can unambiguously fix this by just consciously make things you want global by either assigning them as properties of a known global object or using `var` at the top level scope.  If you want something global, use some coding semantics that explicitly make it global. Then, you will not be subject to this type of transpiling variation. Also, the future of Javascript is all about modules where NOTHING is global except what you explicitly make global and, in fact, globals are entirely discouraged in favor of import/export so moving your code in that direction is a good thing too.

Comment: @jfriend00 Will do. I've been putting off this as well and it shows. For a beginner-medium guy like me, the build tools & complexity of JS is staggering.

Comment: Uhhh, if you're using Babel, you chose a complication that is not required for Javascript.  I write both client and server-side Javascript with no build tools required at all.  If you're going to opt-in to some tools like Babel, you have to learn them well enough that you get the benefit you were seeking when you opted-in to using them.  Also, I don't know where "staggering" comes from.  What is the staggering list of complex build tools you have?  You can also do what some do which is to choose an IDE that integrates tools for you.

Answer (score -1):

[Via MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode):

> First, strict mode makes it impossible to accidentally create global variables. In normal JavaScript mistyping a variable in an assignment creates a new property on the global object and continues to "work" (although future failure is possible: likely, in modern JavaScript). Assignments, which would accidentally create global variables, instead throw an error in strict mode.

Ergo, remove `'use strict'`.

Comment: But...contrary to what the MDN says, I'm doing exactly what I said in my original question and it works. Both `use strict` and `const function = ()` and they're in the global `window`.

Comment: @DanielSmith - Apparently, you're transpiling your code.   The code you write is not what the browser sees.  You have to look at the transpiled code to see what's really happening during transpiling.  That will tell all.